# Get data from some function and use it as default values of arguments of formModel

Tags: angular, forms, model, components

In my Angular component I have

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  userProfile;
  formModel={
    FirstName:"",
    LastName:""
  }
```

And in ngOnInit I have function that gets data

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.service.getUserProfile().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.userProfile = res;
```

What I want is to use that data as default valuse of formModel. Is that possible ? and how ?

Comment: Why not? Just assign the data in the subscribe like you're doing with this.userProfile = res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngOnInit() {
this.service.getUserProfile().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.userProfile = res;
```

In your ngOnInit you have assigned the response to the userProfile.Now you what this data to be displayed on your template.
So there is three ways in which yo can do this particular process:

**Option 1:**
use a flag which you can turn on and off

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.formReadyFlag = false;
      this.service.getUserProfile().subscribe(
          res => {
             this.userProfile = res;
             this.formReadyFlag = true;
      })
}
```

correspondingly in your html you will render the form only after the response is retrieved from the server.

**component.html**

```
<input [(formModel)]="userProfile?.name" *ngIf="formReadyFlag"/>
```

**Option 2:**
ensure that the response which is being assigned has a new reference so that change detection is triggered.

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getUserProfile().subscribe(
          res => {
             this.userProfile = {...res};// shallow cloning to ensure a new reference is formed and assigned to the class variable.
      })
}
```

this option is a less tedious approach to the earlier option.

**Option 3:**
make use of observables and async pipe that way you have less boilerplate code to write and everything works seamingly.This method cannot be used in case you want to perform some operation on the response.

**component.ts**

```
    this.userProfile$ = Observable<any> | Subscription<any>;// Depends on the response type of the service method.   
ngOnInit() {
          this.userProfile$ = this.service.getUserProfile();
    }
```

**component.html**

```
<input [(formModel)]="(userProfile | async)?.name"/>
```

Comment: And where do you assign default values of formModel ??? userProfile is different variable

Comment: from your template the formValue was being st to the response.If your FormModel attribute is being bind to formModel object in your ts then you can assign value directly.

Comment: I generate formModel which is empty. at the same time I call getUserProfile where I receive data for that form. Can you write solution how can I transfer that data as default values for formModel ?

Comment: `if(res) {this.userProfile = {...res};Object.keys(this.userProfile).forEach((item)=>this.formModel[item]=this.userProfile[item])}`.After this make the flag as true.This way you have a default copy of response and also a new copy which you assign to the formModel.

Comment: Awesome happy to help:)